# Scatter Plot of Multiple Y Values for each X coloring each X value

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

For each company name I want to assign a color. I tried playing with color parameter in scatterplot but that gives different colors within company names.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
y = [[0.15,0.25,0.63],[0.69,0.24,0.85],[0.85,0.41,0.73]]
x = [1,2,3]
sns.set_style("dark")
plt.title("Company Records")
for xe, ye in zip(x, y):
    plt.scatter([xe] * len(ye), ye)
plt.xticks([1,2,3]);
plt.axes().set_xticklabels(['ACTP', 'ATC',"LKO"],rotation = 45);
```

Comment: Your code gives a plot with 3 colors for the three companies.

Comment: @QuangHoang I want to set different colors than what is shown by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the custom colors along with zip:

```
colors = ['red', 'magenta', 'pink']
for xe, ye,c in zip(x, y,colors):
    plt.scatter([xe] * len(ye), ye, c=c)
plt.xticks([1,2,3]);
plt.axes().set_xticklabels(['ACTP', 'ATC',"LKO"],rotation = 45);
```

Output:

[image]